# Plot an indicator from another timeframe on current timeframe

Tags: pine-script

On the hourly chart, how can I overlay the daily timeframe's RSI over a 14-day period over my hourly chart's RSI over a 14-hour period?

Comment: You'll need an RSI indicator like this one which can show the current and a higher timeframe signal. You can surely find others in the Public Library if you do not like this one:
https://www.tradingview.com/script/XcGCX8DG-Visual-RSI-LucF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line:
Daily_RSI = security(tickerid, "D", rsi(close,14))

Comment: I'd like to add, that this code will work only in pine-script versions prior to 4. For v4 it should be `security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", rsi(close,14))`